# Read project name and version from Leiningen project.clj file

Tags: clojure, leiningen

How can I query the project group, name and version from a Leiningen `project.clj` file using only `lein` and simple command line utilities without modifying the project file?

I could not find anything useful in `lein help`, like executing code from the command line arguments.

I am thinking about writing a `sed` expression, but I am wondering if there is a simpler way using Leiningen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fully(?) supported by Leiningen, sort of.  In short:

```
$ (lein update-in :version pr -- version ; lein update-in :name pr -- version) | cut -d '"' -f 2
```

This works by abusing the `update-in` command to apply `clojure.core/pr` to the `:version` or `:name` project key.  (You can see all project keys by using just a colon as the member to pr. The just-a-colon feature is described by `lein help update-in`.)

Leiningen requires an actual command too, in addition to `update-in`.  Because `pr` returns nil, I suppose the updates damage the project map and make it unsuitable for real work. The above demo sidesteps the problem by using the `version` command to print Leiningen's own version.

Oddly, the printed version or name appears more than once; thus the `cut` command to take only the first quoted string on each line.  We assume you haven't used quotes in your project name or version!

You can stack `update-in`'s on one command line, but doing so makes the name and version harder to parse from the output.

Comment: Or try `prn` instead of `pr`. It adds a newline.

Answer (score 4):

The contents of `project.clj` is a clojure data structure so you can `read` it e.g.

```
(let [[_ ga version] (read-string (slurp "project.clj"))]
   [(namespace ga) (name ga) version])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just write a Clojure function.  [Java regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) are quite powerful (more than unix `grep`).

Something like this will get you started:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.string :as str]))

(dotest
  (let [txt    (str/quotes->single (slurp "project.clj"))
        result (re-find
                 #"(?ix)                # turn on case-insensitive (i) and freespace (x) modes
                  defproject\s+         # anchor the regex, followed by 1+ spaces
                  ([-a-z0-9]+)\/        # maven group name, followed by a slash
                  ([-a-z0-9]+)\s+       # maven artifact name, followed by 1+ spaces
                  (\S+)                 # version string
                  "
                 txt)]
    (spyx-pretty result)))
```

with result:

```
--------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.2-alpha1    Java 15
--------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
result => 
["defproject  demo-grp/demo-art  '0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'"
 "demo-grp"
 "demo-art"
 "'0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'"]
```

We first convert the double-quotes into single-quotes to simplify the regex and the output.  We use a custom pattern class that includes not only alphanumeric chars but also hyphens.  Clojure `slurp` is handy since it returns the file as a single large string, ignoring the separate lines which is a problem for Unix `grep` if everything of interest is not on the first line.

The above is based on [a simple template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

Feel free to embellish further!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Leiningen lets you evaluate things on the command line, but it does let you start a REPL to which you could pipe some Clojure code:

```
$ echo "(-> '$(cat project.clj) (nth 1) namespace)" | lein repl | tail -n2 | head -n1
"mygroup"
$ echo "(-> '$(cat project.clj) (nth 1) name)" | lein repl | tail -n2 | head -n1
"myproject"
$ echo "(-> '$(cat project.clj) (nth 2))" | lein repl | tail -n2 | head -n1
"0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

But if you want something less bulky, would installing [Babashka](https://github.com/babashka/babashka#installation) be an option?

```
$ bb -i "(-> '$(cat project.clj) (nth 1) namespace)"
"mygroup"
$ bb -i "(-> '$(cat project.clj) (nth 1) name)"
"myproject"
$ bb -i "(-> '$(cat project.clj) (nth 2))"
"0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Add a `println` to omit the quotes:

```
$ bb -i "(-> '$(cat project.clj) (nth 2) println)"
0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a module for this. It will read the default project.clj or from a path.

https://github.com/aneilbaboo/lein-project-reader
[image]